# convert .net date format to javascript format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date-format

I am developping an ASP.NET MVC  application where I use an infragistics grid to display data, I have a date format column where I can display several formats. In my .NET server side, I store format like this :

```
{0:d}
{0:D}
{0:G}
{0:s}
```

My infragistics JavaScript grid can only understand this kind of format :

```
dd/mm/yyyy
dddd d MMMM yyyy
...
...
```

I would like to know how to convert the .NET format to understable JavaScript format without doing tricky string manipulation. 
There is no native converter to pass from this `{0:d}` to that `dd/mm/yyyy` in c#.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

Use `ToString` to format the `DateTime` value.

```
var s = myData.type.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

See [Custom Date and Time Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: See also: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). And note that the format string is case sensitive. `MM` is month and `mm`is minutes.

Comment: This is not my problem, I don't want to specify a format, I already have the format but it's in a .net way.

Comment: A .net `DateTime` *has no format*. It's basically just an `Int64` value (see [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.aspx) under "Remarks" for details). Only its *representation* (i.e. `ToString`) has a format.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ^^ let's create custom converter

```
 public class DateTimeConverter : JavaScriptConverter
    {
      public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
      {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
      }


  public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
  {
    return new Dictionary<string, object> { { "", ((DateTime)obj).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") } };
  }


  public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes { get { return [] { typeof(DateTime) }; } }


}
```

Then let's create custom JsonResult class.

```
public class CustomJsonResult : JsonResult
{
  public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
  {
      if (context == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
      }
      HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ContentType))
      {
        response.ContentType = this.ContentType;
      }
      else
      {
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
      }
      if (this.ContentEncoding != null)
      {
        response.ContentEncoding = this.ContentEncoding;
      }
      if (this.Data != null)
      {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        serializer.RegisterConverters(new [] { new DateTimeConverter () });
        response.Write(serializer.Serialize(this.Data));
      }
  }
}
```

In your Base Controller override Json Method to return CustomJsonResult

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior) {
    return new CustomJsonResult{
        Data = data,
        ContentType = contentType,
        ContentEncoding = contentEncoding
    };
}
}
```

Then let's return our custom Json Format

```
public class AppController : BaseController
{
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  //Assuming there's a variable called data
return Json(data,JsonBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```